# Problema a la hora de funcionamiento de la Aplicación.Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

tengo un problema a la hora de integrar firebase en mi aplicación. Por ejemplo cuando ya tengo programado el botón de inicio de sesión con google y lo pruebo con mi dispositivo, al indicar la cuenta elegida, la aplicación se cierra sola, y a la hora de poner mi correo electrónico y la contraseña como registro, éste no me lleva a la segunda pantalla y en los usuarios de Firebase aparece el correo ni la cuenta de Google. ya he integrado el Sha y todos los paquetes de Firebase agradecería mucho la ayuda.

```
    import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
class ActivityAuth : AppCompatActivity() {


    private val GOOGLESIGNIN = 100
    private val isSuccessful:Boolean = true
    private val isFailure: Boolean = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        }



        // GOOGLE AUTH
        google.setOnClickListener(){
            val googleconf = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build()
            val googleClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleconf)
            googleClient.signOut()

            startActivityForResult(googleClient.signInIntent, GOOGLESIGNIN)
        }

    }

    private fun setup(){

        title = "Autenticación"

        RegisterButton.setOnClickListener{

            if (editTextTextEmailAddress.text.isNotEmpty() && editTextTextPassword.text.isNotEmpty()){
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(editTextTextEmailAddress.text.toString()
                    , editTextTextPassword.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener(){
                    if(it.isSuccessful){
                        ShowHome(it.result?.user?.email ?:"", ProviderType.BASIC)
                    }else{
                        ShowAlert()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        LoginButton.setOnClickListener{

            if (editTextTextEmailAddress.text.isNotEmpty() && editTextTextPassword.text.isNotEmpty()){
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(editTextTextEmailAddress.text.toString()
                    , editTextTextPassword.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener(){
                    if(it.isSuccessful){
                        ShowHome(it.result?.user?.email ?:"", ProviderType.BASIC)
                    }else{
                        ShowAlert()
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (GOOGLESIGNIN == requestCode) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            val intent2 = Intent(this, ChatActivity::class.java)

            if (account != null) {

                val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.idToken, null)
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential)
                ShowAlert()
            }
        }
    }

    // GOOGLE AUTH FINISH

    private fun ShowAlert(){

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("Error")
        builder.setMessage("Se ha producido un error autenticando el usuario")
        builder.setPositiveButton("aceptar",null)
        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }

    private fun ShowHome(email: String, provider: ProviderType){
        val HomeIntent = Intent(this, Homeactivity::class.java).apply {

            putExtra("email", email)
            putExtra("provider", provider.name)
        }
        startActivity(HomeIntent)
    }
}
```

Y este es el código en el activity de Home:

```
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.ContactsContract
import android.text.Editable
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main3.*

    enum class ProviderType{
        BASIC
    }




class Homeactivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3)

        val bundle: Bundle ?=intent.extras
        var email = bundle!!.getString("email")
        var provider = bundle!!.getString("provider")
        setup(email?: "", provider?: "")
    }
    private fun setup(email:String, provider: String){
        title ="Inicio"
        emailTextEdit.setText(email)
        providerTextEdit.setText(provider)
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuando se cierra sola se debe a que está crasheando en algún lugar, te recomiendo que mires el log a ver qué es lo que se está rompiendo, sin eso sería más fácil ganar la lotería que acertar qué le pasa a tu aplicación.

Comment: La cosa está en que aunque yo tenga conectado mi dispositivo físico cuando da el error, en la pantalla no aparece ningún tipo de error, y si me estoy equivocando, dónde podría encontrar el log?

Comment: En android studio en el apartado LogCat o en la consola donde se ve lo que imprime en `System.out.print` debería aparecerte el stack trace de tu error

Comment: @Benito-B me está dando en el log direntes errores como bien puede ser SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Comment: @Benito-B este error también me lo está dando, y sinceramente no se a que se refieren estos errores ya que soy nuevo en todo el tema de programación E/e.myapplicatio: [qarth_debug:]  get PatchStore::createDisableExceptionQarthFile method fail.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: Mírate algún tutorial de cómo utilizar catlog para debugar una aplicación de Android, es imposible explicártelo bien en comentarios, y hay muchísimos tutoriales breves que te lo explicarán de maravilla, entonces podrás poner el error concreto que está crasheando la aplicación

Comment: @Benito-B muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo, pasa un buen día!

Comment: Una vez que localices el error, no dudes en actualizar la pregunta, seguro que podremos arreglarlo. Por cierto, en catlog revisa si ves algo que ponga NullPointerException, es una excepción muy común cuando se está empezando

Answer (score 0):

Si obtienes el error:

> SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Configura tus `EditText` para que no acepten sugerencias configurando los flags:

```
emailTextEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS)
providerTextEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS)
```